# Is there a way to download your current HTML page not using JavaScript?

Tags: html

I'm looking for a way to download an HTML page not using JavaScript.

So if I'm in an email, for example, having a button that will download the email template as an HTML file.

Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? with what code language do you want to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: The server can re-send page with application/octet-stream mime header, which will give the save dialog

Comment: basically i want to be able to download my email html from outlook or gmail which i know that are not supporting any scripting (javascript or other)